# c++ linked list only outputting every other element

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list filled with chars. The following code is only saving every other element, what can I modify to fix this? Attached are the two functions used in reading input from the user.

```
void LList :: InsertTail(element thing) {
        // PRE : the N.O. LList is valid
        // POST : the N.O. LList is unchanged, except that a
        //      new listnode containing element thing has been
        //      inserted at the tail end of the list

        listnode * temp;

        temp = new listnode;

        temp -> data = thing;
        temp -> next = NULL;
        if(head == NULL)
                head = temp;
        else
                tail -> next = temp;
        tail = temp;
}






void LList :: ReadForward() {
        // PRE: the N.O. LList is valid
        // POST : the N.O. LList is valid, all of its
        //      previous listnodes have been deleted, and
        //      it now consists of new listnodes containing
        //      elements given by the user in foward order
        char userval;
        Clean();
        cout <<  "Enter the message: ";
        userval = cin.get();
        cout << userval;
        while (cin.get()!= SENTINEL) {
                InsertTail(userval);
                userval = cin.get();
                cout << userval;
        }
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(80, '\n');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your whileloop in ReadForward.

Each time you call cin.get() you are reading another character - hence skipping that character from being added.

Change it to:

```
while(userval) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `while()` loop inside the `ReadForward()` method:

```
while (cin.get() != SENTINEL) { <----
  InsertTail(userval);
  userval = cin.get();
  cout << userval;
}
```

On the marked line you call `cin.get()` but never store it anywhere. This discards every other character from being read because you're only storing a character *after* you've read another one.

The fix is to store the result of `get()` inside `userval` every time the loop runs.

```
cout <<  "Enter the message: ";
while (cin >> userval) {
  cout << userval;
  InsertTail(userval);
}
```